How to Implement Overflow Handling in Go
I was coding and I wanted to add too many numbers, which I get from the user. I think that if the result of adding these numbers is greater than int64, it should give an error and indicate an overflow.
I tried a lot but didn’t get the right result.
I expect that if a number is greater than the maximum value of int64, it should give me an overflow error.
